# C++ enum type as a function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, enums

I am working on C++ code trying to build a FlipIt game program. I have a header file and a .cpp file. In the header file I have a flipit class where one of the functions is an enum type function. For example in the header file FlipIt.h:

(enum declaration)

```
enum  Color  { clear_ = false, solid_ = true };
```

(the function)

```
Color  fetch( int  row, int  col ) const;
```

(In the FlipIt.cpp file this is what I implemented the function in the class as)

```
int FlipIt::fetch( int  row, int  col ) const
```

When I do this VS2010 says IntelliSense: declaration is incompatible with "FlipIt::Color FlipIt::fetch(int row, int col) const"

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your promised returnvalue of `FlipIt::Color` in your declaration of your method differs from the type you provide in your implementation. And `enum` is not `int`.
Try

```
FlipIt::Color FlipIt::fetch(int row, int col) const { }
```

for your implementation.

Comment: Ok it is still a declared member function of the FlipIt class in FlipIt.h if I try that for my implementation?

Answer (score 2):

But `Color` is not `int`. It's `enum` and it has some underlying type (that's depends on compiler), but it's another type anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You must distinguish the enum type was defined in which namespace.if your enum was just defined in header file, not in cpp file. You include the header file, the linker can find the type of definition, if you define in class, you must add class prefix. The linker can find the definition of the type.
  So, if your enum type was defined in global area there is no problem. if you define in class, you must use "Class::Type".